# Proper way to use Vuex with Vuelidation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuelidate

I'm working on a Vue front end for an application that requires all form data be persisted locally before submitting to the backend in case a network connection issue causes an interruption of service. I'm using Vuex to maintain all the form data across the application, so that it can be persisted and restored to/from local storage as required.

A second requirement is form validation, for which I intend to use the Vuelidate library. The documentation suggests that to use Vuelidate without a `v-model`, all that is required is `this.$v.touch()` in the event function. That is what I have tried, but it does not seem to work.

See the example below:

```html
<template>
  <form>
    <input name="full-name" v-model="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "AForm"
    computed: {
      fullName: {
        get() { return this.$store.state.fullName }
        set(name) {
          this.$v.touch();
          this.$store.dispatch("updateFullName", name);
        },
      }
    },
    validations: {
      fullName: minLength(4);
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I examine `$v.fullName`, the value is just equal to `true`. When I look at the entire `$v` object, I see `$anyDirty: false`.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hawking-51o7e)

Comment: If i remember well in Vuelidate you need more then this to validate a form. There are examples in documentation too https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-form-submission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Validation config malformed

The validation config should be:

```js
export default {
  /**
   * Validation Config Format:
   *
   *   validations: {
   *     PROP_NAME: {
   *       RULE_NAME: RULE
   *     }
   *   }
   */
  validations: {
    //fullName: minLength(4), // DON'T DO THIS

    fullName: {
      minLength: minLength(4)
    }
  },
}
```

### `$touch`

It looks like you used `this.$v.touch()`, but it's supposed to be `this.$v.$touch()`. However, since the computed prop sets only one prop, you should just invoke `$touch()` on that prop (i.e., `$v.PROP_NAME.$touch()`) *after* the prop is changed through the Vuex action.

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    fullName: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.fullName;
      },
      set(name) {
        //this.$v.touch() // DON'T DO THIS

        this.$store.dispatch('updateFullName', name)
        this.$v.fullName.$touch()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Using Vuelidate with Vuex]